# python list of cdef class, avoiding explicit casts all over

Tags: python, types, cython

I'm writing a Cython wrapper around an external C library.  The library produces a tree data structure (it's an HTML parser) and the Cython code needs to construct secondary trees and walk them.  So I have class definitions like this:

```
cdef class TreeNode:
    cdef list children  # List<TreeNode>

    cpdef debug_dump(TreeNode self, object fp)

    # ... other fields and methods ...
```

and then methods that do things like this:

```
cpdef debug_dump(TreeNode self, object fp):
    fp.write("... stuff about self ...")

    for c in self.children:
        (<TreeNode>c).debug_dump(fp)
```

This all works, but I find myself having to write `(<TreeNode>x)` all over the damn place.  In some cases it gets really ridiculous:

```
# Otherwise, this block might be mergeable with its immediate
# previous sibling.
else:
    pclass = (<TreeNode>(<TreeNode>self.stack[-1]).children[-1]).tagclass
    if (tclass == pclass or (tclass == TC_PARA and pclass == TC_HEADING)):
        self.stack.append((<TreeNode>self.stack[-1]).children.pop())
        (<TreeNode>self.stack[-1]).tagclass = TC_PARA
        (<TreeNode>self.stack[-1])._depth = <int>depth
```

Is there any way to declare that a variable is a list of some concrete type, so that I don't have to sprinkle these casts all over the place?

(Note: I'm aware of the possibility of using `vector<TreeNode>` in `--cplus` mode, but this is an interface to an external library and I'm not sure it's safe to use its headers from C++, so I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve `--cplus` mode.  It may also become necessary to expose these lists to normal interpreted Python code in the future, which AFAIK won't work with `vector`.)